# template path hints showing when turned off?

Tags: admin, template-hints

I have template path hints turned off but some modules have the template path hints still around them. Weirder still if I go to another page on the site it comes up with path hints for parts that wouldn't have the hints on other pages.. anyone experienced this?

Comment: did you clear the cache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably those blocks are cached.
You turned on the template path hints, the cache was clear, called a page and some blocks got cached.
Then you disabled the template path hints but you did not clear the cache and some blocks still return the cached HTML containing the template path hints.
Unfortunately the flag for template path hints is not included in the cache key of the blocks.
Conclusion: Clear the cache.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, though why would it only do it now when I've been doing this for a few weeks now?

Comment: It worked :) thank you, though I'd still like to know why it randomly choose today to cache it?

Comment: Maybe the cache expired when you did this and the new cache was created.